# How to check if one or two integers are -1, among four integer variables in total, Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have 4 integer variables

```
r1, r2, c1, c2
```

They can be any integer values. I want to find out which of them is/are `-1`.

The rule is `r1` and `r2` cannot be -1 at the same time; `c1` and `c2` cannot be -1 at the same time.

I can use `if` statement, but it can be cumbersome:

```
if r1 == -1:        
    if c1 == -1:
        # do action a
    elif c2 == -1:
        # do action b
    else:  # c1 and c2 are both not -1
        # do action c
elif r2 == -1:
    if c1 == -1:
        # do action d
    elif c2 == -1:
        # do action e
    else:  # c1 and c2 are both not -1
        # do action f 
else:  # none of the four integers is -1.
    # do action g
```

Could you please show me some more elegant and efficient algorithm?

Comment: This logic seems suspect: the comment `# none of the four integers is -1.` is incorrect.

Comment: Do you just need to check that `r1`, `r2` are both not -1 and `c1`, `c2` are not -1 ?

Comment: If you want to perform specific operations depending on value of each variable then `if else` might be the only way!

Comment: `if r1 == r2 == -1 or c1 == c2 == -1: print("rule violation")`

Comment: @Sandesh.Patil I can actually think of a few ways that doesn't involve `if... else...` but none of them would be as readable and as elegant as the original implementation.  That said, if OP confirms it's just a check against `-1` and no separate actions needed, it'll be *much* simpler.

Comment: @Idlehands Can you explain that please? I couldn't think of any other way!

Comment: @TeraBaapBC Using a `dict` as a switch is one possible way, say `d = {(-1, 0, -1, 0): action_a}` and check against `d.get((r1, r2, c1, c2))()`.  But because of the possible states of the integer it's not as simple as stating `0` for non-`-1` values so it's another layer of confusion.  It's possible, but not pretty at all.

Comment: Oh, That's right

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have an efficiency problem here, but you can improve readability by checking for the two illegal scenarios you mentioned explicitly:

```
if r1 == -1 and r2 == -1:
    raise Exception("r1 & r2 are -1")
elif c1 == -1 and c2 == -1:
    raise Exception("c1 & c2 are -1")
else:
    print("ok!")
```

You have some options to avoid the if/else entirely (a dictionary, for instance, with keys as tuples of `(r1, r2, c1, c2)` and the operations you wish to invoke as values), but I think they would all be a net loss insofar as readability goes.

Comment: I think you're just adding more statements, since he wants to perform various operations. And he's in need of efficient one

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the rules you mentioned i.e. it cannot happen that r1=r2=-1 and c1=c2=-1, we can assume that there are cases when we do not need to perform all four checks to find out if your variables are -1 or not.

In order to utilize these rules, you need to have some data structure that reflects order of your variables and enables to skip checks that are not required (e.g. r1 = -1 than we do not need to check r2).

While this perhaps is not more efficient CPU time-wise, it follows the logic that it is not necessary to perform all of the variable checks in each scenario:

```
d = {'r1' : 0, 'r2' : -1, 'c1' : -1, 'c2' : 0}

def isMinusOne(x):
    if x == -1:
        return x

i = 0
while i < len(d):
    if isMinusOne(list(d.values())[i]) is not None:
        print(list(d.keys())[i])
        if i == 0 or i == 2:
            i += 2
        else:
            i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```